# Cannot list files in a directory using ftplib

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I have tried to connect to a ftp server.

```
import sys
from ftplib import FTP
import os, sys, os.path
import time

server = ""
user = ""
password = ""
ftp = FTP(server)
ftp.login(user, password)

ftp.cwd('CKR reference drawings (DEC2017)')
ftp.cwd('GIS drawings')

ftp.nlst()
```

And I get a timeout error.

However, when I use the command prompt in windows, I can get the list of files using dir.
[image]

I want to download all the files in a folder. So I want to get the list and then download them all.

Would proxy server be an issue? I am using company network. But, cwd command works.

Comment: Where do you get the timeout? On `nlst` call? Show us a log file (`FTP.set_debuglevel`). + Anyway, ftplib defaults to a passive mode (what is generally better). While `ftp.exe` supports an active mode only. Usually the passive mode works better than the active. But maybe your FTP server has the passive mode broken. Try `set_pasv(false)`.

Comment: Yes. The nlst call. After I set to passive mode to false, I got an empty list which is not correct.

Comment: So show us log file for both active and passive mode. + Can you retrieve the directory listing using the passive mode with any FTP client that supports it (like WinSCP)?

Comment: I got it now. Empty list because they are folders not files.

Comment: OK, so it works in the active mode. You should make the passive mode working anyway.